# Using IPv6 link-local addresses to ping between VMs in internal VirtualBox network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ping, ipv6

I'd like to test this network configuration in fully virtualized enviroment, while I don't have access to physical lab.

I am using 2 VM Guest machines (Guest OS is Archlinux), each configured with NAT adapter and one internal network adapter. Pinging between these machines on IPv4 using internal adapter addresses is no problem.

I would like to set up link-local addresses on internal interfaces and use ping6 to test out reachability:

```
VM1: fe80::1:1/64
VM2: fe80::1:2/64
```

From my understanding, this should work no problem when these two hosts would be connected to same physical switch right? However, after using

```
ping6 -I enp0s8 fe80::1:1/64
```

I only get

```
unknown host
```

Is this problem only VirtualBox specific and should work on real machines or is something wrong with my assumptions on how IPv6 link-local addresses work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real address is `fe80::1:1`, or `fe80::1:1%enp0s8` with the scope identifier.

Prefix length (the `/64`) is only used when *configuring the interface* and is **not** part of the address. It is equivalent to the "subnet mask", and you don't give the subnet mask to `ping` either, do you?